# How to find students in the same classes

Tags: sql, oracle, grouping

I'm newer to SQL and struggling to properly define my data.  I'm trying to identify all students who are share **two** or more of the same classes.

For instance:

```
ID  | Class
------------
1      Math
1      Science
2      Math
2      Science
3      Math
3      English
4      Math
4      English
5      Math
5      History
```

Results:
Math and Science = ID 1 and 2
Math and English = ID 3 and 4

ID 5 is not returned since they only share 1 class with the others.

Comment: _Specify_ the expected result-set.

Comment: Hi jarlh,  I'm trying to think of the best way to display this.  I was asked to "to identify all students enrolled in the same class sections of multiple sections".  So instead of just a count, I need both the ID numbers and the classes that they share.  I'm not even sure how to get the results where there's 2 or more classes grouped together with then all of the id numbers for that given combination.  Any suggestions or ideas are welcomed!

Comment: Why is 5 not returned? it's sharing math and history

Comment: @alex067, no other student has the combination math and history.

Comment: Hi alex, thanks for taking a look.  I'm looking for students where where they have 2 or more of the same classes.  ID 5 shares Math, but no other classes.

Comment: Add the student 6, with Math, Science and English. What's the expected result now?

Comment: With an added ID 6 in Math, Science, English the results would be IDs 1,2,3,4 for classes Math, Science, English.  Is this even possible?  I'm thinking there's too many variables at play to organize the results.

Answer (score 0):

Do a self join and group by both ids:

```
select t.id id1, tt.id id2, 
  listagg(t."Class", ',') within group (order by t."Class") classes
from tablename t inner join tablename tt
on t.id < tt.id and t."Class" = tt."Class"
group by t.id, tt.id
having count(*) > 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=445d7e9de263709ced5da3a0482ffe03).
Results:

```
| id1 | id2 | classes      |
| --- | --- | ------------ |
| 1   | 2   | Math,Science |
| 3   | 4   | Math,English |
```

Edit, another option:

```
with cte as (
  select t.id id1, tt.id id2, 
    listagg(t."Class", ',') within group (order by t."Class") classes
  from tablename t inner join tablename tt
  on t.id < tt.id and t."Class" = tt."Class"
  group by t.id, tt.id
  having count(*) > 1
)
select t.classes,  
  listagg(t.id, ',') within group (order by t.id) students
from (
  select classes, id1 id from cte
  union 
  select classes, id2 from cte
) t  
group by t.classes
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=eb1ab4086df09cd7952a9c3ba23ff9dc).
Results:

```
CLASSES         STUDENTS
English,Math    3,4
Math,Science    1,2
```

Comment: Thanks forpas - this looks promising.  Any ideas for a work around on the group_concat?  Oracle databases doesn't allow it.

Comment: thanks so much!  These results are looking good.  another question - is it possible to build out the amount of ID numbers?  That is, if more than 2 id numbers share the same group of classes, can they all be listed in one row of data?  For instance, I got

ID 1    ID 2    Classes  <br/>
------------------------------  <br/>
1            3       Math, Science  <br/>
1            4       Math, Science  <br/>
<br/>
Can it display  <br/>
ID 1    ID 2      ID3      Classes   <br/>
----------------------------------------  <br/>
1            3         4         Math, Science  <br/>

Comment: Try my 2nd query  with different data.

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate the subjects into a collection and then compare the intersection of the collections:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID, Class ) AS
 SELECT 1, 'Math'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 1, 'Science' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 2, 'Math'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 2, 'Science' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 3, 'Math'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 3, 'English' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 4, 'Math'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 4, 'English' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 4, 'Physics' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 5, 'Math'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 5, 'History' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TYPE string_list AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
```

**Query**:

```sql
WITH classes ( id, classes ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         CAST( COLLECT( Class ) AS string_list )
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY id
)
SELECT c1.id,
       c2.id,
       ( SELECT LISTAGG( COLUMN_VALUE, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY COLUMN_VALUE )
         FROM   TABLE( c1.classes MULTISET INTERSECT c2.classes )
       ) AS shared_classes
FROM   classes c1
       INNER JOIN classes c2
       ON (   c1.id < c2.id
          AND CARDINALITY( c1.classes MULTISET INTERSECT c2.classes ) >= 2 )
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ID | ID | SHARED_CLASSES
> -: | -: | :-------------
>  1 |  2 | Math,Science  
>  3 |  4 | English,Math
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=75f7798264ed2233fcfb8586989ada5d)*